# Matlab class multiple accessors for same data

Tags: c++, matlab, class, unions

I'm trying to translate a class from C++ to Matlab. In C++, the same data can be accessed in multiple ways because the values are declared as a `union`.

However, it seems like the only way to do this in Matlab is to override `subsref` and `subsasgn`, which opens up a can of worms of having to parse methods.

Is there a different way to handle this? I saw some comments from 2014 indicating there wasn't

This is the C++ `enum` in question:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Euler
{
    public:
       union
       {
          T m[3];
          struct
          {
             union { T x; T yaw; T psi; };       // m[0]
             union { T y; T pitch; T theta; };   // m[1]
             union { T z; T roll; T phi; };      // m[2]
          };
       };
};
```

Comment: Please show the relevant `union` declaration in C++. It is possible to interpret a series of bytes as a series of integers or floats, and other conversions might be possible too. An answer to this question depends on the specifics of the `union`.

Comment: Ah, this is a very different question than I originally thought! `union` is often used to combine different types in the same memory space, sometimes abused as a way to `reinterpret_cast<>`. Here it is just used to address the same values under different names.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution: forget about these names, and translate this class as a simple array, indexing `m.x` as `m[1]`, `m.roll` as `m[2]`, etc. This might not be great for some use cases, but certainly is the most efficient solution.

The alternative solution requires creating a custom class. `subsref` and `subsasgn` are not necessary, it is possible to declare dependent properties and define getters and setters (though it's not pretty!):

```matlab
classdef Euler
    properties
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
       z = 0;
    end
    properties (Dependent)
       yaw, pitch, roll;
       psi, theta, phi;
    end
    methods
        function value = get.yaw(obj)
            value = obj.x;
        end
        function value = get.pitch(obj)
            value = obj.y;
        end
        function value = get.roll(obj)
            value = obj.z;
        end
        function obj = set.yaw(obj,value)
            obj.x = value;
        end
        function obj = set.pitch(obj,value)
            obj.y = value;
        end
        function obj = set.roll(obj,value)
            obj.z = value;
        end
        % Add same methods for psi, theta, phi.
    end
end
```

You can now do:

```matlab
e = Euler;
e.x = 1;
e.yaw    % returns 1
e.roll = 5;
e.z      % returns 5
```

That is, the object has properties `x`, `y`, `z`, `yaw`, `pitch` and `roll` (and after adding appropriate setters and getters also `psi`, `theta` and `phi`), but only stores three values. The values of e.g. `yaw` and `x` are linked, and always identical.

Comment: Can you show an example how to use the methods for your alternative solution please ?

Comment: I understand now, thank you for editing your answer.